# High Charts - Show series data of Multiple Charts

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have created a Highchart for Ionic App, which has Bar Graph, Spline and Line all plotted in the same graph. I'm able to see the Series label of only one Graph at a time when I hover my mouse over the Data. I want the series Label of all the chart data when hovered over the graph.

Like in the image here.
[High Charts Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ0CT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Set shared tooltip to true:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  ...
}
```

**Offical example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true/

**API on shared tooltip:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared

Comment: Thanks! This Works :)